# Is there a JSON-returning ASP.NET MVC for ajaxComboBox already?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, combobox

The combobox in question http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxComboBox

I forgot to note, I want to use it on ASP.NET MVC, i.e. sans the viewstates and the whole shebang

Comment: ViewState is an ASP.NET WebForms abstraction. I'm not sure what that has to do with a jQuery plugin at all.

Comment: to prevent various ASP.NET Ajax controls answers ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just *use* the `ajaxComboBox` then?  ASP.NET MVC doesn't have "viewstates and the whole shebang" as you put it, it's heavily reliant on you crafting the view (HTML) from the model that is presented through the controller (although you should optimially present something more like a modelview to the view, but that's off-topic).

First you would create a method on a controller which would return the items.

Then, in your view, you just have to write (in place) the url of the route to the method on your controller as the first parameter to `ajaxComboBox` and it should work.

Comment: That's right, the jquery.ajaxComboBox does not impose any kind of web framework.

Comment: It's in PHP, I'm thinking maybe somebody already converted it to ASP.NET MVC and google haven't indexed it yet ^_^

Comment: @Hao: `ajaxComboBox` is *not* in PHP.  The back end that is feeding the data to the front end is in PHP, but you can have *any* back end feed the data to `ajaxComboBox`.  That's like saying PHP is the only web platform that can generate XML or JSON, which isn't the case.

Comment: re: converted **it**, I pertain to ajaxComboBox.php. I know well that ajaxComboBox front-end is written in jQuery, and it reads JSON structure from the string generated by ajaxComboBox.php. What I'm interested at is the back-end side of things. Instead of using ajaxComboBox.php, I'm trying to find if there's already an equivalent ASP.NET MVC that generates JSON for ajaxComboBox's requests

Comment: @Hao: I'd recommend asking the question differently then, because the emphasis is on the front end side.  As for the back end, there is a Json method/extension method on the Controller class in ASP.NET MVC which will return JSON content.  That should suit your needs.  If not, I'd look into Json.NET (or the DataContractJsonSerializer class) and creating your own action result which will serialize your content appropriately.